# Stop/pause audio when window is closed on touch screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-audio

I'm having a hard time figuring out how I can stop/pause the playing audio file when the user press on another link or close the popup window.

As for now the user always have to hit the pause button to stop the audio.

I have tried to add `stop()` and `pause()` to the JavaScript without no luck.

This is what I have so far:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;

  if (target.hasAttribute('data-toggle') && target.getAttribute('data-toggle') == 'modal') {
    if (target.hasAttribute('data-target')) {
      var m_ID = target.getAttribute('data-target');
      document.getElementById(m_ID).classList.add('open');

      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  if ((target.hasAttribute('data-dismiss') && target.getAttribute('data-dismiss') == 'modal') || target.classList.contains('modal')) {
    var modal = document.querySelector('[class="modal open"]');
    modal.classList.remove('open');

    e.preventDefault();

  }
}, false);
```

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #000000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 9999;
}

.modal-window {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, .9);
  width: 30%;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover, .close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-text {
  color: #000;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.close:hover, .close:focus {
  color: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.open {
  display: block;
}

#player {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
    <div class="col-left">
        <ul>
            <li data-target="modal_1" data-toggle="modal"> Modal1 <span class="headp"><img src="img/headp.svg" height='22px'/></li>
            <li data-target="modal_2" data-toggle="modal"> Modal2 <span class="headp"><img src="img/headp.svg" height='22px'/></li>
            <li data-target="modal_3" data-toggle="modal"> Modal3 <span class="headp"><img src="img/headp.svg" height='22px'/></li>
            <li data-target="modal_4" data-toggle="modal">Modal4<span class="headp"><img src="img/headp.svg" height='22px'/></li>
            <li data-target="modal_5" data-toggle="modal">Modal5 <span class="headp"><img src="img/headp.svg" height='22px'/></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-right">
        <ul>
            <li data-target="modal_6" data-toggle="modal">Modal6<span class="headp"><img src="img/headp.svg" height='22px'/></li>
            <li data-target="modal_7" data-toggle="modal">Modal7 <span class="headp"><img src="img/headp.svg" height='22px'/></li>
            <li data-target="modal_8" data-toggle="modal">Modal8<span class="headp"><img src="img/headp.svg" height='22px'/></li>
            <li data-target="modal_9" data-toggle="modal">Modal9<span class="headp"><img src="img/headp.svg" height='22px'/></li>
            <li data-target="modal_10" data-toggle="modal">Modal10<span class="headp"><img src="img/headp.svg" height='22px'/></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="modal_1" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-window">
        <span class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</span>
        <p>Audiofile name</p>
        <audio id="player" controls>
            <source src="https://sample-videos.com/audio/mp3/crowd-cheering.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are many mistakes in your HTML e.g. `<span>` tags that are never closed. Be sure you have valid HTML first.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `pause()` function (see it on [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_pause.asp)). You could even auto-play the audio as the modal opens (although I advise you not to since it's always better to warn the user beforehand).

Get your element by its id (`#player` here) and set it to `pause()`

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    
    // getting the player ID
    var player = document.querySelector("#player");

    if (target.hasAttribute('data-toggle') && target.getAttribute('data-toggle') == 'modal') {
        if (target.hasAttribute('data-target')) {
            var m_ID = target.getAttribute('data-target');
            document.getElementById(m_ID).classList.add('open');

            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }

    if ((target.hasAttribute('data-dismiss') && target.getAttribute('data-dismiss') == 'modal') || target.classList.contains('modal')) {
        var modal = document.querySelector('[class="modal open"]');
        modal.classList.remove('open');
        
        // pause on modal closing
        player.pause();
        
        e.preventDefault();

    }
}, false);
```

```css
/********** The Modal *********/

.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: none;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #000000;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    z-index: 9999;

}

.modal-window {
    position: relative;
      background-color: rgba(250,250,250,.9);
    width: 30%;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
}


/****close button ****/

.close{
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-text{
  color: #000;
}

.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.open {
    display: block;
}


#player{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
    <div class="col-left">
        <ul>
            <li data-target="modal_1" data-toggle="modal">Modal1 <span class="headp"><img src="img/headp.svg" height= '22px'/></span></li>
            <li data-target="modal_2" data-toggle="modal">Modal2 <span class="headp"><img src="img/headp.svg" height= '22px'/></span></li>
            <li data-target="modal_3" data-toggle="modal">Modal3 <span class="headp"><img src="img/headp.svg" height= '22px'/></span></li>
            <li data-target="modal_4" data-toggle="modal">Modal4 <span class="headp"><img src="img/headp.svg" height= '22px'/></span></li>
            <li data-target="modal_5" data-toggle="modal">Modal5 <span classa="headp"><img src="img/headp.svg" height= '22px'/></span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-right">
        <ul>
            <li data-target="modal_6" data-toggle="modal">Modal6 <span class="headp"><img src="img/headp.svg" height= '22px'/></span></li>
            <li data-target="modal_7" data-toggle="modal">Modal7 <span class="headp"><img src="img/headp.svg" height= '22px'/></span></li>
            <li data-target="modal_8" data-toggle="modal">Modal8 <span class="headp"><img src="img/headp.svg" height= '22px'/></span></li>
            <li data-target="modal_9" data-toggle="modal">Modal9 <span class="headp"><img src="img/headp.svg" height= '22px'/></span></li>
            <li data-target="modal_10" data-toggle="modal">Modal10 <span class="headp"><img src="img/headp.svg" height= '22px'/></span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- The Modal -->

<div id="modal_1" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-window">
        <span class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</span>
        <p>Audiofile name</p>
        <audio id="player" controls>
            <source src="https://sample-videos.com/audio/mp3/crowd-cheering.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't offer a **.stop()** method for the audio element. Luckily there's a **.pause()** method though. All you have to do is get a reference to your audio player element and tell it to pause.

```
document.getElementById("player").pause();
```

Here's a working example:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      var target = e.target || e.srcElement;

      if (target.hasAttribute('data-toggle') && target.getAttribute('data-toggle') == 'modal') {
        if (target.hasAttribute('data-target')) {
          var m_ID = target.getAttribute('data-target');
          document.getElementById(m_ID).classList.add('open');

          e.preventDefault();
        }
      }

      if ((target.hasAttribute('data-dismiss') && target.getAttribute('data-dismiss') == 'modal') || target.classList.contains('modal')) {
        var modal = document.querySelector('[class="modal open"]');
        modal.classList.remove('open');
        modal.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0].pause();
        e.preventDefault();

      }
    }, false);
```

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #000000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 9999;
}

.modal-window {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, .9);
  width: 30%;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

/****close button ****/

.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-text {
  color: #000;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.open {
  display: block;
}

#player {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div class="col-left">
    <li data-target="modal_1" data-toggle="modal"> Modal1 <span class="headp"><img src="img/headp.svg" height= '22px'/></li>
        <li data-target="modal_2" data-toggle="modal"> Modal2 <span class="headp"><img src="img/headp.svg" height= '22px'/></li>
        <li data-target="modal_3" data-toggle="modal"> Modal3 <span class="headp"><img src="img/headp.svg" height= '22px'/></li>
        <li data-target="modal_4" data-toggle="modal">Modal4<span class="headp"><img src="img/headp.svg" height= '22px'/></li>
        <li data-target="modal_5" data-toggle="modal">Modal5 <span class="headp"><img src="img/headp.svg" height= '22px'/></li>
      </div>

      <div class="col-right">
        <li data-target="modal_6" data-toggle="modal">Modal6<span class="headp"><img src="img/headp.svg" height= '22px'/></li>
        <li data-target="modal_7" data-toggle="modal">Modal7 <span class="headp"><img src="img/headp.svg" height= '22px'/></li>
        <li data-target="modal_8" data-toggle="modal">Modal8<span class="headp"><img src="img/headp.svg" height= '22px'/></li>
        <li data-target="modal_9" data-toggle="modal">Modal9<span class="headp"><img src="img/headp.svg" height= '22px'/></li>
        <li data-target="modal_10" data-toggle="modal">Modal10<span class="headp"><img src="img/headp.svg" height= '22px'/></li>
      </div>
</div>
    </div>

    <!-- The Modal -->


    <div id="modal_1" class="modal">

      <!-- Modal content -->
          <div class="modal-window">
        <span class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</span>
      <p> Audiofile name</p>
      <audio id="player_modal_1" controls>
          <source src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/Glade_jul%2C_dejlige_jul.ogg" type="audio/mpeg">

        </audio>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: thank you but this seems only work for the first audio clip.

Comment: `var m_ID = target.getAttribute('data-target');` is 'converting' the data.target attribute into a html element which you try to access later on using: `document.getElementById(m_ID).classList.add('open');` Unfortunately you just have one DIV with an ID of **modal_1** (`<div id="modal_1" class="modal">`) so it fails for the others (modal_2 modal_3...).

Comment: I'm not sure if I can give you advise here because I don't know what you want to achieve. One simple solution would be adding other empty DIVs with IDs of modal_2 modal_3.

Comment: I have other modals with the Id's of modal _2, modal_3, modal_4 etc. they all have sound clips witch keeps on playing if the modal window is closed, except for the first modal.  I would like the other modals to stop playing the soundclips when the user close them.

Comment: I think I know what you mean now. Your other DIVs (modal_2 modal_3 ...) surely have another audio element inside. Give it an unique ID like `<audio id="player_modal_2" controls>` for modal_2 and change `document.getElementById("player").pause();` to `modal.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0].pause();` I modified my example above to reflect those changes.